# VCS: managing multiple feature pull requests

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Assuming I am expanding some project hosted on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) with **multiple** features (managed by mercurial).

If I build up the features one on top of the other (linear local history) I have a local code base that has all the features I need, but the maintainer of the package cannot pick and choose the features he likes. (Because they build on each other.)

If I build up each feature in a separate branch based on the origin master, all the feature PRs are independent of each other (allowing the maintainer to pick and choose), but I no longer have a unified local code base with all my required features.

How does one solve this problem? With patch queues? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for both actually: create a separate feature branch (anonymous heads, maybe named by means of a bookmark) and pull request for each feature.

Additionally, for your own benefit, and maybe also for others to check it all quickly, merge those into your main development branch, your main line.

In principle mercurial has the system of phases and allows for non-publishing repositories which allows to keep a draft history and allows you to easier make updates - but that's afaik something which bitbucket does not yet (fully?) support.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there any advantage to merging the features into the main line rather than rebasing the features onto the main line (obviously keeping the original feature changesets)?   On a separate issue: why are not all repositories 'non-publishing'? Are there any gotchas when using non-publishing repos that are publicly acessible?